# gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink doesn't work (va errors)

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have ubuntu 16.04. I've tried to install gstreamer by this tutorial:
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html but it didn't work for me (can not find packages). So i tried to use this:

```
list=$(apt-cache --names-only search ^gstreamer1.0-* | awk '{ print $1 }' | grep -v gstreamer1.0-hybris)
sudo apt-get install $list
```

after installing gstreamer I've tested how it works by:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink
```

and got this log:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2948): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVideoTestSrc:videotestsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
Freeing pipeline ...
```

May be I've installed gstreamer uncorrect. If you  know how to do it right, pls answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstall OpenCV lib (it has gstreamer inside)

Answer (score 1):

The sink does not work with NVIDIA card for some reason. nveglglessink worked for me instead:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! nveglglessink
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an nvidia card. And Gstreamer tries to use hardware decoding over that but it fails - probably because driver and hardware dont't play together nicely.

Try to do uninstall the `gstreamer-vaapi` package. Then the FFmpeg plugin should do the encoding (if you have it installed). Once you get started you can still consider hardware decoding options at a later stage.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I've already fixed it (I reinstall OpenCV lib and it works for me)