# gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink (does not work for me!)

Tags: gstreamer

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, and I followed the guidelines listed on https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c to install gstreamer.

I think my installation has problem as I did not see any test source with this pipeline:

```
u2@u2:~$ gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'autovideosink0-actual-sink-vaapi': gst.vaapi.Display=context, gst.vaapi.Display=(GstVaapiDisplay)"\(GstVaapiDisplayDRM\)\ vaapidisplaydrm2";
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

I would expect to be able to see the video test source minimally.

Comment: I think it selected DRM mode.. so its decoding to some raw HDMI device or similar? This specific mode is headless I think.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but no I was not displaying on HDMI devices (ext monitors), just on my laptop. Do you know if it's due to gstreamer-vaapi causing this issue? Many thanks again!

Comment: It says something about DisplayDRM which kind of sounds like it does some decoding on the DRM code path which is not easily displayed. I guess the auto mode is not want you want on your setup. Maybe you need to setup more sinks, or be more specific which sink to use.

Comment: Thank you Florian, I am uncertain if my gstreamer installation is valid if I can't get this basic pipeline to work. This is because I used to be working on Ubuntu 16.04 with a more complicated pipeline which works perfectly fine. However, after I shifted over to Ubuntu 18.04, my gstreamer pipeline doesn't work as intended. I read that this simple pipeline is suppose to work if the gstreamer is installed properly.

Comment: Again, there is no error. The pipeline is playing. You can probably verify that by checking CPU usage. Your expectation what is supposed to happen is different. Try `videotestsrc ! glimagesink` instead.

Comment: It worked, thanks Florian. What is the reason autovideosink couldn't work for my case? I have another pipeline that used to work before I upgraded my PC from 16.04 Ubuntu to 18.04.3. I was using autovideosink and fpsdisplaysink which worked fantastically previously but now I could not see anything.

Comment: You would have to check the code how the preference of video sinks are traversed I guess and see why the DRM vaapi sink gets selected. You selected an "auto" mode - so its kinda automatic. If you want a specific pipeline it is a good idea to control it the way you want and not make any assumptions that it will do the right thing automatically. It can depend on hardware, installed software packages..

Comment: Thanks Florian, appreciate it. While I would like my existing pipeline (more complicated) to continue working in my new setup, I will mark this thread as tick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! autovideosink doesn't work (va errors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654161/gst-launch-1-0-videotestsrc-autovideosink-doesnt-work-va-errors)

Comment: Thanks @h22, unfortunately I'm still having issue. I have an NVIDIA card with cuda 10 installed. But it says no element 'nveglglessink'.

Comment: This issue was because monitor was connected with HDMI cable but DP cable.was fixed when I used HDMI cable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got the same issue with you: autovideosink can play video but doesn't display it in a window. Try:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! ximagesink`

Also, glimagesink works for us.

Hope to know more working sink elements.

*To play a local .mp4 video, use:

`gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/path/to/your/video.mp4 video-sink="ximagesink"`

**To make autovideosink works, try:

```
sudo apt-get remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

To be honest, above beginner-level gears blocked us for a while, and we had very hard time to resolve such simple questions :)

Hope it is helpful to all gstreamer newbies !

Comment: At my end its still not working, gives error `WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "ximagesink"`

Comment: @AbhishekAnand on my install, `ximagesink` came with `gst-plugins-base1.0`

Comment: Thank su much for the answer. After removing gstreamer1.0-vaapi the video is showing. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LST version with GStreamer 1.0.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand try ```glimagesink```